# How to remove the shallow clone warning from HomeBrew

Tags: git, homebrew

```
➜  ~ brew info test 
Error: No available formula with the name "test" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
```

I have modified the git remote address to mirror address of homebrew before. Maybe it's relevant to this but I don't know.

Comment: Note that as of Dec 2020 Homebrew no longer allows shallow clones anyway. https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/9383

Comment: @GrishaLevit this should probably be the new accepted answer!

Comment: @paulcm good point, added an answer.

Answer (score 181):

As of Oct 2020 Homebrew [no longer creates shallow clones](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/8883) when being installed, and as of Dec 2020 updating existing shallow clones is [not allowed](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/9383) either.

(This makes the original question about silencing the warning moot).

---

If a shallow clone is configured, a message containing text like the below will be shown:

> ```
> Error:
>   homebrew-core is a shallow clone.
>   homebrew-cask is a shallow clone.
> To `brew update`, first run:
>   git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow
>   git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask fetch --unshallow
> ```

It is now *required* to perform the unshallow process by running the `git` command(s) in the error message.

Note: This process may take a long time to complete without providing feedback.

---

For some details about the motivation for this change, see [this discussion](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/226) on Homebrew's GitHub page, specifically:

> There are two major downsides of shallow cloning:
>
> 1. It places a massive computation burden on GitHub's servers, which have to *dynamically* compute a fresh delta between what you have and the latest commit, on every `brew update`. (With full clones, GitHub can simply send you all the commits that happened after your last pull, and your local Git client takes care of the rest.)
> 2. Because of [1], it makes it far more likely that GitHub will rate-limit Homebrew operations, which will make it suck for everyone.

<sup>--gromgit [Dec 5, 2020, 12:29 AM EST](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/226#discussioncomment-147717)</sup>

And also this additional text [added](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/9447/files) to the error message:

> This restriction has been made on GitHub's request because updating shallow
> clones is an extremely expensive operation due to the tree layout and traffic of
> Homebrew/homebrew-core and Homebrew/homebrew-cask.

Comment: Thanks for all the details. Can you clarify what exactly is the problem with shallow clones? Shouldn't they be preferred since only the latest version is downloaded?

Comment: It just hangs when you do this command though :-/

Comment: I thought mine had hung too, it just took forever to start doing something. First: `git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" fetch --unshallow`, then `git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask" fetch --unshallow`. This is all beyond me.

Comment: Does this mean that if we don't manually unshallow our homebrew install, that we won't receive updates even when running "brew update"?

Comment: @OliverDixon, wait longer, it's a gigantic repo, it took me minutes to execute this.

Comment: @TheKarateKid that's right. If you have an old (pre-Dec 2020) version of homebrew installed, it will let you update to the latest version, but then, when you try to update again, the latest version will prompt you to run the git unshallow commands and will refuse to update if you do not.

Comment: Came here to find the answer: "Note: This process may take a long time to complete without providing feedback."

Comment: I’ve waited a couple of hours, no feedback in Terminal, nothing seems to be happening in Activity Monitor either (shouldn’t something show somewhere)?

Comment: to whom wants to know if the git still pulling the changes, add `-v` (verbose move) to show progress after long wait.

Comment: for me, it took almost 20 minutes to start (I am on a 400 MBPS connection if that gives a good reference point), and I used the verbose -v command, which helps. seriously, you simply run the command, and with no feedback whatsoever, just 'wait'. it's enough to drive even an experienced developer mad. but, it is what it is.

Answer (score 40):

somehow the unshallow is not working for me, I wait like 10 mins but nothing show up, even with `-v` option.

Just found one possible solution that might working(at least working for me).

You can remove the repository and clone again to get latest one.

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/
rm -rf homebrew-core
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core.git
```

same command for homebrew-cask if you need to update that too

all the credits belong to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65563588/3992524)

Comment: This is a huge improvement over the original `git pull --unshallow` command. This needs more upvotes

Comment: It works. It is also slow but at least we can see the progress

Answer (score 31):

Under the cover Homebrew uses Git for version control, and a shallow clone
is one that doesn't contain all history revisions/commits, for efficiency and data volume.

Actually, in most cases the warning can be safely ignored, as the formulae being searched for probably isn't available.

But if you're really looking for some formulae which might existed in the past, Just do what it suggests:

> To get complete history run:
>
> ```
> git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
> ```

This way Homebrew could search for formula that existed only in the past but removed at some point.

Comment: I had same question as OP. Perhaps they are wondering as I am why I need to do that (I never saw this warning until relatively recently), what purpose it serves, do I need to do that every time I do a `brew info`. Is this just a temporary glitch? I use git on a regular basis but have no experience with shallow vs. deep clones.

Comment: Decided to try it and find out:

> $ git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
> error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Comment: Simplest explanation for a "shallow clone" is that it's simply a clone of the git repository without the revision history thereby reducing the git repo footprint. You can also specify "depth" to reduce the amount of revision history obtained from a git clone. Essentially you get the latest version of the codebase without the bloat.

Comment: Pulling a deep clone of a large, old and active repo can use a huge amount of bandwidth and time. The historic versions are obsolete and so of no value for ”typical” usage. So it is a good optimisation for brew to shallow clone. The warning is simply that as it doesn't have the entire history it cannot distinguish a typo from a deletion. The vast majority of times it will be a typo.

Answer (score 15):

I have update repo through git pull --unshallow

Update homebrew-core

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
git pull --unshallow
```

Update homebrew-cask

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask
git pull --unshallow
```

Answer (score 11):

I would advise against unshallowing the clone because it cramps disk space, makes the lookups slower and enables you only to install obsolete or unmaintaned applications.

There is currently no way to silence this warning. It was proposed in this [Github issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3513#issuecomment-348599067) but then ignored.

The function `deleted_reason` which prints the message contains a `silent` argument but afaik there is no way to use to use something like `silent` from the CLI commands which later call `deleted_reason`.

Comment: This is the better answer, IMO. My takeaway is: if you're a developer, fetch the unshallow clone, as in ryenus' answer. If you're a user, just leave it.

Answer (score 10):

Fetch the repo using the `--unshallow` flag:

```
git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow
```

Comment: How long should it normally take? I'm not sure if it's running. It's just stalling.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this, the logic Homebrew uses for checking if your clone is shallow is by checking if either of `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-{cask,core}/.git/shallow` exists.

One can work around that check by moving the `.git` directory out of the repo; example command to do so (run in the Terminal):

```
for tap in /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-{cask,core}; do \
  mv $tap{/,}.git ; \
  echo "gitdir: $tap.git" >$tap/.git ; \
done
```

Reference: [Setting up .git folder in a custom location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337025/setting-up-git-folder-in-a-custom-location)

Homebrew foundation is unfortunately incredibly hostile towards their community and I wouldn't be surprised if they patched this soon.

Nonetheless, this is a lifesaver for me and possibly other people in similar situation to mine. However, if your life doesn't immediately depend on this, perhaps do them a favor and just unshallow.

Answer (score -1):

```
git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
```

This command should run with `sudo` and it would work.

```
sudo git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
```

[image: Terminal Picture]

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the right way but does work

`git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow`

Wait some minutes. After that you'll see something like this.

```
Resolving deltas: 100% (723461/723461), completed with 4329 local objects.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
   4d2aadabe6c..eab34538365 master     -> origin/master
```

then you could paste this again to update Homebrew and that's it.

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29963989)