# homebrew/core is a shallow clone in Fish shell

Tags: homebrew, fish

I tried to install something using `brew install` and this thing pops up

```
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
```

and when I copied that thing to make it run, this happens

```
fish: $(...) is not supported. In fish, please use '(brew)'.
git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
        ^
```

What does it means and how can I fix these things? Is there's a workaround to ignore or fix?

Additional information about my workstation:

- MacOS Mojave
- Homebrew version 2.0.2
- Does run `brew doctor` and it shows up as no problem
- Using Fish shell (of course I do)

---

**Update 1 :**
It looks like I am an idiot leaving the `$` there. 
I did try to fix it with you guys suggestions, and this what happened.

Removing the `$` from the command, like so

```
git -C "(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
```

and this happens

```
fatal: cannot change to '(brew --repo homebrew/core)': No such file or directory
```

---

**Update 2 :**
Also, @VonC asked me did `brew --repo homebrew/core` path exists by asking me to run these following line

```
brew --repo homebrew/core
```

and it comes up as this

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
```

which indicates that the repository path is still valid and ready to use

Comment: It tells you how to fix it: Leave out the dollar sign.

Comment: I'm curious how long you have used the `fish` shell since you did not recognize that the error message told you what was wrong with the copy/paste command you tried to run.

Comment: Looks like I am too stupid to understand what it just trying to hint. I have updated the  question with some more discoveries I have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I did a double oopsies.
Thanks to all comments to me that I am doing an oopsies. I appreciate it a lot.

Instead of typing

```
git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
```

which fish does not really likes `$` in that line,

> use this instead :
>
> ```
> git -C (brew --repo homebrew/core) fetch --unshallow
> ```
>
> no `$` and `"`. 
>   AAAAND that's it.

Please comment if this does not help. I still doubt that really resolves this question or not lol

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [fish-shell/issue 1405](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1405#issuecomment-53998397)

> In bash, `$(...)` is equivalent to backticks, except it's supported inside a double-quoted string.
>   Fish does not use `$(...)` or `backticks`, it uses `(...)` instead

So:

```
git -C (brew --repo homebrew/core) fetch --unshallow
```

[Issue 159](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/159) discusses the support of `$()` command substitution syntax.
Since 2012.

```
fatal: cannot change to '(brew --repo homebrew/core)': No such file or directory
```

Then double-check what `brew --repo homebrew/core` returns, and if the path exists.

As an alternative, [seen here](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/7560#issuecomment-270046911):

```
git -C $HOMEBREW_CORE fetch --unshallow
```

Using `""` should be supported, as seen in "[How to remove the shallow clone warning from HomeBrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45784973/6309)", but not advisable, from [glenn-jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976754/homebrew-core-is-a-shallow-clone-in-fish-shell/54977302?noredirect=1#comment96771237_54977302).

> Simplest explanation for a "shallow clone" is that it's simply a clone of the git repository without the revision history thereby reducing the git repo footprint. You can also specify "depth" to reduce the amount of revision history obtained from a git clone.

In your case, if you need the full history, a `fetch --unshallow` is needed.

Comment: Looks like I am too new to Fish. I have updated on my discoveries.

Comment: `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core` is where the path is. I still don't understand what do they want from me lol

Comment: You don't want the command substitution inside quotes. Demo `echo (seq 10)` vs `echo "(seq 10)"`

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly, and included your comment for more visibility.