# brew upgrade node failing with error Error: node not installed , even when I do have old version of node installed

Tags: node.js, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Mac OS 10.13.6 with homebrew installed, today had to upgrade it because of new homebrew policy

[Can't update or upgrade Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65160625/cant-update-or-upgrade-homebrew/)

after doing this, tried upgrading node to latest version and got below error

```
Warning: You are using macOS 10.13.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.

Error: node not installed
```

In fact I do have old version of node installed

```
node -v
v12.0.0
```

how to solve this weird problem ?

**Note**:

Few weeks back I did below to use older version of node

[Install NVM On Mac With Brew](https://jamesauble.medium.com/install-nvm-on-mac-with-brew-adb921fb92cc)

I'm really confused atm, who is managing node on MAC ? Is it NVM / homebrew ?

Comment: If you run `brew list` does node show as an installed formula?

Comment: no, it's not showing. What are different ways to install node ? I think to make use of yarn; I have uninstalled node and installed it using nvm.

Comment: NodeJS.org has `pkg` file for installing node on macs: https://nodejs.org/en/download/. You mentioned `nvm` there is also `nodevm`, which personally I like better than nvm

Comment: so I should install node either by homebrew / nvm / n or nodevm right ? In this case node installed by others should be removed ?

Comment: Using the install pkg is fine as well. Regardless, I would say yes, you should know the install source. And if you are not sure how things are installed now uninstall the current and reinstall so you know.