# Having trouble updating python from 2.7 to 3.9 on MacBook

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-2.7, homebrew

I'm a newbie to python and am having a really rough time trying to update the python version on my MacBook. I use a MacBook with macOS Monterey and with python installed over a year ago. When I type python --version in the terminal, the version printed out is v2.7. I'm trying to self-learn Django for web development, and need python version 3.9. I did a google search and found a site that gives a step by step tutorial on getting up and running with Django. As instructed on this site, I tried running "brew install python3" but I get the following message:

"Error:
homebrew-core is a shallow clone.
To `brew update`, first run: ----and some info here----

What is confounding is that even though I get an error, the terminal then shows hundreds of errors before the process finally ends. Could someone provide guidance on how I (being a noob) can resolve this mess and update python to the latest version (3.9), so I can do an install of Django?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat - I tried the first command from the solution in the link that you provided - I copied and pasted the first git command and hit enter, and the cursor is just stuck in the terminal - I don't see any messages or anything. Does that mean that something else is missing? Or would I need to wait longer for the system to do its thing?

Comment: Honestly don't know, but I believe you should try the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65563588/14991864) by [Fernando Martínez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2115173/fernando-mart%c3%adnez) on that question then? Someone does mention in the comments about the command you ran being stuck.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat - yes, that seemed to work! Its not perfect (I still see python 2.7 when I type the version, but from inside pycharm, I'm now able to change the base interpreter to python version 3 and successfully install django), but I'm keeping my fingers crossed that this will work! Thanks for your help - accepting your solution as the answer.