# original brew update Error needs to run git fetch --unshallow, but got another git fatal

Tags: homebrew

```
$ brew update
Error: homebrew-core is a shallow clone. To `brew update` first run:
  git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" fetch --unshallow
```

I tried to run above command: `git ... --unshallow`
but I got another error:

```
fatal: dumb http transport does not support shallow capabilities

$ brew -v
Homebrew 2.6.0-104-g24f7898
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision b1ef15; last commit 2020-12-05)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 443e7; last commit 2020-08-27)
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: This exact same thing happened to me as well, coincidentally today. Did something happen with brew cask?

Comment: Yup using shallow clones is now not allowed due to the high load it was generating on GitHub's servers.  Some more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65243764/1072229)

Answer (score 59):

I dug a little after trying to deal with the git repo, but the simplest thing that fixed it for me was untapping and then retapping the casks repo

```
brew untap homebrew/cask
brew tap homebrew/cask
```

that put everything back in order.

I haven't RTFM'd lately, but I'm guessing this has something to do with how casks seem to be moving into the main homebrew repo (or at least that's how it seems as a naive user).

Comment: This issue happened to me after my upgrade to MacOS Big Sur.
And the answer from @john definetly solved my issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I tried to run:
`$ git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" fetch`

then:
`$ git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" fetch --unshallow`

`brew update` seems OK now.

Comment: For other users tryining to use this tip, please have some patience if your terminal is not responding. 1 minute was the waiting time on my system for each line.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem with brew update getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting this

```sh
$ brew update
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/myf/homebrew-formulas failed!
```

Notice the **myf/homebrew-formulas** in the last line.
This is one of my old repos not accessible anymore.

I got it solved with

```sh
$ brew untap myf/homebrew-formulas

Untapping myf/formulas...
Untapped 5 formulae (37 files, 63KB).
```

*Other commands I tried*

```
$ brew upgrade
$ brew update-reset
$ brew doctor
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved with:

```js
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew
rm -rf homebrew-core
rm -rf homebrew-cask
brew upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

`brew tap --repair` made the trick for me